# Oracle query for time range

Tags: sql, oracle

The below is a practice for myself:

I've created a table with some values, as:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test AS
SELECT ROWNUM ID, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+(LEVEL*5/24/60/60)date_time , 111 person_id
FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (24*60*60)/5 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Now, I updated table , `person_id = 222` for `date_time` between `5:30 am` and `6:30 am`

```
UPDATE my_test
SET  person_id   = 222
WHERE date_time >= trunc(SYSDATE)+ 5/24 + 30/24/60
 AND DATE_TIME  <= trunc(sysdate)+ 6/24 + 30/24/60;
```

I need to take the number of persons in each hour, so I've written a code like:

```
SELECT time_range,count(distinct person_id) PERSON_COUNT
FROM (
select person_id , date_time,
case TO_CHAR(date_time,'hh24') when '00' then '12 AM - 01 AM' 
             when '01' then '01 AM - 02 AM'
             when '02' then '02 AM - 03 AM'
             when '03' then '03 AM - 04 AM'
             when '04' then '04 AM - 05 AM'
             when '05' then '05 AM - 06 AM'
             when '06' then '06 AM - 07 AM'
             when '07' then '07 AM - 08 AM'
             when '08' then '08 AM - 09 AM'
             when '09' then '09 AM - 10 AM'
             when '10' then '10 AM - 11 AM'
             when '11' then '11 AM - 12 PM'
             when '12' then '12 PM - 01 PM'
             when '13' then '01 PM - 02 PM'
             when '14' then '02 PM - 03 PM'
             when '15' then '03 PM - 04 PM'
             when '16' then '04 PM - 05 PM'
             when '17' then '05 PM - 06 PM'
             when '18' then '06 PM - 07 PM'
             when '19' then '07 PM - 08 PM'
             when '20' then '08 PM - 09 PM'
             when '21' then '09 PM - 10 PM'
             when '22' then '10 PM - 11 PM'
             WHEN '23' THEN '11 PM - 12 AM' end time_range
FROM my_test
WHERE date_time >= trunc(SYSDATE)
AND date_time < trunc(SYSDATE)+1
ORDER BY date_time)
GROUP BY time_range;
```

Its working fine without expected ordering. ( The order by time_range not gives the expected as it is string in the outer query).

I need to order by time_range, and any simple and easy codes for the above are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause is always the last to be interpreted in a single query, here however it is in a subquery so the main query `GROUP BY` will "overwrite" your `ORDER BY`.

You could write for instance:

```
SELECT time_range, COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) PERSON_COUNT
  FROM (SELECT person_id,
               date_time,
               CASE TO_CHAR(date_time, 'hh24')
                  WHEN '00' THEN
                   '12 AM - 01 AM'
               /*[snip]*/
                  WHEN '23' THEN
                   '11 PM - 12 AM'
               END time_range
          FROM my_test
         WHERE date_time >= trunc(SYSDATE)
           AND date_time < trunc(SYSDATE) + 1)
 GROUP BY time_range, TO_CHAR(date_time, 'hh24')
 ORDER BY TO_CHAR(date_time, 'hh24');
```

Also I'm not a fan of your `time_range` expression. You could rewrite it simply as:

```
to_char(date_time, 'HH PM - ') || to_char(date_time + 1/24, 'HH PM') time_range
```

Edit: apparently you need the complete query:

```
SELECT time_range, COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) PERSON_COUNT
  FROM (SELECT person_id,
               date_time,
               to_char(date_time, 'HH PM - ') 
               || to_char(date_time + 1/24, 'HH PM')  time_range
          FROM my_test
         WHERE date_time >= trunc(SYSDATE)
           AND date_time < trunc(SYSDATE) + 1)
 GROUP BY time_range, TO_CHAR(date_time, 'hh24')
 ORDER BY TO_CHAR(date_time, 'hh24');
```

Comment: wow. Thats so simple. Ive used: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) ,
     time_range
FROM
     (SELECT date_time, person_id,TO_CHAR(date_time, 'HH PM - ')
          || TO_CHAR(date_time + 1/24, 'HH PM') time_range
     FROM my_test
     )
GROUP BY time_range;` but still the ordering is not done in this logic

Comment: You need an `ORDER BY` clause. Ordering is never done by magic.

Comment: you can see that `ORDER BY` will not make effect for the above comment I used, ie; according to your second simpler query. Please check it.

Comment: Can't you, like, combine the two elements of my answer? =)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should have the `order by` in the *outer* query rather than the inner query.  `order by` in inner queries is generally not guaranteed to work.

But, even if you put:

```
order by date_time;
```

at the end, you still won't get what you want.  For that, try ordering by the `date_time` itself, as in:

```
order by max(date_time);
```

Here is an example of the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html) on `order by` in subqueries:

> An ORDER BY clause allows you to specify the order in which rows
>   appear in the result set. In subqueries, the ORDER BY clause is
>   meaningless unless it is accompanied by one or both of the result
>   offset and fetch first clauses or in conjunction with the ROW_NUMBER
>   function, since there is no guarantee that the order is retained in
>   the outer result set. It is permissible to combine ORDER BY on the
>   outer query with ORDER BY in subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for the info about sub-queries, but I am looking for ordering the outer query in the mentioned `time_range`

Answer (score 0):

```
select case TO_CHAR(date_time,'hh24') when '00' then '12 AM - 01 AM' 
         when '01' then '01 AM - 02 AM'
         when '02' then '02 AM - 03 AM'
         when '03' then '03 AM - 04 AM'
         when '04' then '04 AM - 05 AM'
         when '05' then '05 AM - 06 AM'
         when '06' then '06 AM - 07 AM'
         when '07' then '07 AM - 08 AM'
         when '08' then '08 AM - 09 AM'
         when '09' then '09 AM - 10 AM'
         when '10' then '10 AM - 11 AM'
         when '11' then '11 AM - 12 PM'
         when '12' then '12 PM - 01 PM'
         when '13' then '01 PM - 02 PM'
         when '14' then '02 PM - 03 PM'
         when '15' then '03 PM - 04 PM'
         when '16' then '04 PM - 05 PM'
         when '17' then '05 PM - 06 PM'
         when '18' then '06 PM - 07 PM'
         when '19' then '07 PM - 08 PM'
         when '20' then '08 PM - 09 PM'
         when '21' then '09 PM - 10 PM'
         when '22' then '10 PM - 11 PM'
         WHEN '23' THEN '11 PM - 12 AM' end time_range,
count(person_id) person_count
FROM my_test
WHERE date_time >= trunc(SYSDATE)
AND date_time < trunc(SYSDATE)+1 
group by TO_CHAR(date_time,'hh24')
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks, for the info for usage of `group by` its, correct but the you need to use `count( distinct person_id)` instead. and anyway I've got simpler query by @Vincent